# Pivot functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

The current table looks like this

```
ID|reg_ num|student_name|maths|computer |language|total
--+--------+------------+-----+---------+--------+------
1 |001     |james       |50   |50       |50      |150
2 |002     |john        |60   |50       |50      |160
3 |003     |alex        |50   |70       |50      |170
4 |004     |david       |50   |50       |80      |180
```

But i need the table in such a way that:

```
register_ number|subjects |marks
----------------+---------+---
              1 |maths    |50 (again)
              1 |languages|40 ....
```

Till all the subjects of the register_number 1 is listed out, and I need a follow up by reg_number - 2 till the number of records are found in that particular table

I am pretty sure that the [ pivot ] function to be used but don't know how to add multiple column of a particular row based on a particular [register_number] entity in the row

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your data directly in the question.  And also, Google for "pivot query SQL."

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use unpivot 
try this query

```
select u.register_number, u.subject, u.marks
from studentmarks s
unpivot
(
  marks
  for subject in (Maths,computer,...)
) U;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `unpivot` rather than `pivot` :

```
select t.register_number, tt.subjects, tt.marks
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('maths', maths),
              ('computer', computer),
               . . . ,
              ('total', total)
     ) tt (subjects, marks);
```